# Share data without a website using DeepLink in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, share, deep-linking

Let´s say you have an app where the user can create content and store it in the app, in this case meals to track his nutrients.

The meal would be stored in a data class and that data class in a list of all his meals. Now it would be useful to be able to share a meal to other users with the same app, thus a meal doesn't have to be created multiple times if for example two people eat the same meal.

I understand that sharing content between apps via a link that also opens the corresponding app on click can be done by `DeepLinks`, but it always seems to involve links **that access the content via servers** and not by the link itself.

Instagram for example uploads the content to its servers and when shared, a link to this content on the servers is shared.

As the app with the meals isn't about uploading meals to other users but rather personal tracking, *such a link to the meals on a server isn't available*.

While searching about this topic I found little information about custom domains for `DeepLinks`, which ***don't point to a website but to the app itself and have the content inside the link itself***.

Of course I tried but such links **don't seem to get recognised as links** and don't appear at the `App Links Assistant` in Android studio, even though implemented according to the limited [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Heres my code:

- Manifest.xml

```
<application

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="appname" 
                  android:host="open.app"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

- Share.kt

  ```
       val deepLink = "appname://open.app.?mealId=${encodedData}"

       val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
           action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
           putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deepLink)
           type = "text/plain"
       }
       val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
       startActivity(context, shareIntent, null)
  ```

I tried sharing via email, WhatsApp and notes, also the devices have the correct version of the app but the link is not clickable, **what am I doing wrong**?